# Which visa for exchange

Tags: visas, australia, minors, german-citizens

My son 15 years will be in Australia for Exchange (school), after the 3 month exchange we would like to travel 14 days with the whole family in Australia. Which visa needs my son ? We are Germans.

Comment: Have you tried asking the organisation arranging the exchange?

Comment: Private organized….

Comment: Your son will need a [Student (subclass 500) visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/student-500).

Comment: I don't get the close votes. It's three months, not years.